# How to detect the single tap in DispatchTouchEvent method in forms android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, touch

Am using DispatchTouchEvent and need to detect a single tap, for that considered the down point and up point, when both are same, detected the single tap.
But this works fine in some android devices, but in some device, there in a pixel difference in down and up point. How to overcome this?

```
         public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {  
            touchDownPoint = new Xamarin.Forms.Point(e.GetX(), e.GetY());
        }
        else if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {   
            var position = new Xamarin.Forms.Point(e.GetX(), e.GetY());               
            if (touchDownPoint == position) // this condition not gets satisfied in some devices
            {
                // single tap detected.
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Move)
        {              
        }

        return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
    }
```

Comment: What is the pixel difference in down and up point mean? Could you provide more details about the some "device"?

Comment: It is working in android 9, 10 version, Nokia , MoTO e device and all, but in samsung tab, down and up points are not same, down and up points have a difference of about 5 (approx), and it varies on each touch.